# What algorithm is GaussView using for the clean function?

Tags: computational-chemistry

A colleague showed me [GAUSSIAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_(software)) 09 which comes with GaussView 5
for drawing structures. What impressed me was the snappiness of the
*Clean* function.

*What algorithm is used for the Clean function?*

The [GaussView 5 Reference](http://gaussian.com/g16/gv5ref_nav.pdf.zip) can be downloaded from the publisher’s
web site. It doesn’t seem to contain the information that I’m looking
for.

*Background:* As part of a project called
 [SAN – Self Aware Network](https://github.com/feklee/san), I have a similar problem, though with
 additional constraints. To find the distribution of points in space,
 I implemented a genetic algorithm. Unfortunately, with large
 structures, this algorithm tends to get stuck in local minima. I
 documented the algorithm in the report [SAN: Location Optimizer](https://feklee.github.io/san/notes/145c7131-6c7f-49cb-8ecc-07658b5c4a96/).
 A mathematician friend implemented a
 [solution using gradient descend](https://github.com/davidblitz/san-optimizer). Yesterday, he showed me some
 nice results, but it’s nowhere as snappy as GaussView.

## Update

I also contacted Gaussian technical support. Their response:
“Unfortunately, no. We do not have additional documentation about this
function, other than what is already present in the GV5 manual. This
function just uses a very simple MM expression with crude parameters
just to provide a simple way to "clean" a structure drawn "by hand" in
GaussView. It is certainly not intended to give accurate geometries
(it is expected that one is going to use some other model in Gaussian
to run a geometry optimization and get a good geometry). The purpose
is simply as another aid as part of building a structure in GaussView,
so one may "clean" a structure faster (not always) than otherwise
using "modify bond", "modify angle", "modify dihedral" tools.”

Comment: I think it is unlikely you will find a direct answer to this question if the software is owned by Gaussian. Gaussian is notoriously strict about who they share their source code with and does not like when people share details of their algorithms. As an aside, I am almost certain that this "clean" function is not optimizing the structure. It is essentially making a sophisticated guess at the structure, so you might see faster convergence with GD if you use the clean output as an initial guess. Also, finding the global minimum of large structures is notoriously difficult and often unnecessary.

Comment: This webpage gives general information about what clean is doing :[http://flex.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/texi/gview/clean.htm](http://flex.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/texi/gview/clean.htm). Basically, it's using van der waal's radii and various weights assigned to different internal coordinates to make a good guess. Again, you'll need to do a real optimization if you are interested in true minima.

Comment: @jheindel Thanks! Unfortunately nothing new: This seems to be simply the online version of the reference guide I linked to in my question. It gives a rough idea about how the force field function *f* is constructed. What I am most interested in is: *What algorithm is used to find the minimum of f?* (e.g. *gradient descent algorithm* or *genetic algorithm*)

Comment: I would be very willing to bet that they are using gradient descent since they will already have a code for this to do actual geometry optimizations. If not, then it would be a Newton-Raphson, but given that they recommend 150 steps, this seems unlikely.

Comment: First off, it's worth stating that GaussView is not developed by Gaussian, Inc. You might find that [AMPAC GUI](http://www.semichem.com/ampac/ampac-gui-shots.php#modgm) looks familiar.

Comment: I strongly suspect that GaussView is using steepest descent or conjugate gradients on a very simple force field (e.g., Lennard-Jones). Based on your comments, it looks like you want to read up on Distance Geometry embedding or some of the Stochastic Proximity Embedding and Self-Organizing papers by Agrafiotis.